# I do not understand why setting a value defined in the execution context of a constructor function with a set property does not change the value

Tags: javascript

In the code snippet below I set `_value` to 45 with a set function that gets defined on the instance. It appears `_value` is defined on the instance as soon as I use the `setValue` property, however when I call `logValue()`, I get 25. If I uncomment the call to `yo()`, the output becomes:

```
25
25
45
```

#### Code snippet:

```js
var constructor = function() {
  var _value = 25;
  constructor.yo = function() {
    console.log(_value);
  }
  constructor.prototype.logValue = function() {
    console.log(_value);
  }
  Object.defineProperty(this, "getValue", { get: function() {return _value;}});
  Object.defineProperty(this, "setValue", { set: function(input) { _value = input;}});
};
var instance = new constructor();
var instance2 = new constructor();
instance.setValue = 45;
instance.logValue();
//constructor.yo();
console.log(instance.getValue);
```

Comment: Why are you using two properties? Why not make one property `value` and define the getter and setter in the same object? e.g. `Object.defineProperty(this, "value", { get: function() {return _value;} set: function(input) { _value = input;} });`

Comment: Please Note: constructor is (>=ES6) a reserved keyword and should not be used as variable name.

Comment: @Mijago got it, thanks.

Comment: You define the contructor var _value = 25; the next is on correct path of running , nothing strange for me.

Comment: @evolutionxbox No reason.

Comment: @Mijago [No, it is not](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-keywords).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That `_value` variable is local to the `constructor()` function. A new instance of that variable is created each time `constructor()` is called. Now, in that function, each time it's called, you're also recreating the `yo()` function as a property of the `constructor()` function. That means that on the second call to `constructor()`, the previous value of the "yo" property will be overwritten with a new function.

Thus, when you modify `_value` through the *second* instance object, you're modifying that `_value` variable from the closure created in the *second* call to `constructor()`. Because there's only one "yo" property, that's the value that'll be logged when it's called.

If you were to create a third instance, you'd see the same effect: "yo" would be overwritten once again, and the value (before you change it) would go back to the default of `25` when interrogated via "yo".

While it's not exactly *wrong* to set up a property like your "yo" property in a function like that, in this case it's not clear what it accomplishes. It would probably be better to have "yo" be a property of the constructed object instead of the constructor function itself.

*edit* — Felix Kling correctly points out that redefining `logValue()` on the prototype *inside* the constructor will have similar (bad) effects.

Comment: `logValue` basically has the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This seems right. I am still trying to wrap my head around it. The yo property was there to see how javascript behaves.

Comment: @RyanWatson it takes some time to get the feel of JavaScript. A good rule is that code in the constructor is for initializing the *instance*, and that prototype setup is separate. The new `class` syntax makes keeping that organized a little easier.

Answer (score 1):

`constructor.prototype.logValue` is redefined each time an instance is created and `logValue` always prints `_value` in the last instance.

```
var constructor = function(val) {
  var _value = val;
  constructor.prototype.logValue = function() {
    console.log(_value);
  }
};

var instance = new constructor(30);
var instance2 = new constructor(50);
instance.setValue = 45;
instance.logValue(); // prints 50  _value from instance2
instance2.logValue();  // prints 50 _value from instance2
```